# Validating input field of the reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using basic `input` component for validating `name`.

It is accepting only characters and not allowing any special characters to enter.
 This condition is working fine.

**Validating code:**

```
      firstname: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+')]],
```

But i need one more requirement:
1) It should accept **even a single character**, but it is accepting minimum 2 character by default.How can i change this default behaviour??

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-fom5td?file=app/add-customer/add-customer.component.html) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the regular expression you have written in Validators.pattern(), it looks for 2 characters minimum, remove on [a-zA-z] block and it should work fine as you desire.

Comment: Ya i resolved this, but i want space between the characters and should avoid space at the beginning of the 1st character.

Comment: For ex It should accept:  **1)arun kumar** but it should not accept **2)  arun kumar**.

Comment: try this regular expression [a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z ]+)* should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try reduce regex pattern to `[a-zA-Z]+` It will take from 1 to unlimited amount of characters. Yor current regex takes char then unlimited amount of characters so it need minimal two characters to match.

Comment: It's working fine, but space at thing it shouldn't take. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try ^[a-zA-Z]+?[ ][a-zA-Z]+$  It will accept unlimited characters and additional space with unimited characters

Comment: This is allowing **space between words** and not allowing at the **beginning of the first word** but  my 1st issue which i mentioned in the question exists again if i use this expression.